# Instruments points out low memory warning, but very low memory usage

Tags: ios, memory, instruments

I used instruments to test my app. In my app, there is a tableView which loads many images. When I scroll the tableView, the instruments points out many "low memory warning" flags. But the memory usage is just below 5MB and my app runs well. I'm confused about this situation. Why such low memory usage and the instruments still gives memory warnings? Is this a normal situation?

Comment: Also make sure you're measuring the dirty memory in the VM Tracker on the device, not just Allocations.  Dirty memory is usually what causes the memory warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal to receive memory warning, it might not even be your app that is consuming all the memory. As long as you're using reasonable amount of memory, no memory leak and handle memory warning properly in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning`, you should be alright.